# Spring Webflux with Transactions

Tags: transactions, spring-webflux

Is it possible to have transaction management using Spring Webflux? We will be building a microservice and I'm considering using Spring Webflux but I'd like to make sure that a PUT/POST request that mutates state can be atomic. For example if the request that is received needs to:

- Update state in the microservice's own database
- Make an update to a downstream service via a REST API

Is it possible to wrap the steps within a Transaction so that the changes are atomic?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `TransactionTemplate` in your reactive code:

```
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

// save to DB method
public Void saveMembers(Member m1, Member m2) {
    saveMember(m1);
    saveMember(m2);
}

// your reactive method 
public Mono<Void> saveMembersAsync(Member m1, Member m) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> 
        saveMembers(m1, m2)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes of course you can have transaction!.
Using NoSql database like Cassandra or Mongo the reactive ext via reactive stream are native but in case of relation database some problem can happen.
Of course you can wrap the your repository call in a Mono and use schedulder for async feature but I not am so secure that the transaction is spanned correctly many framework like JPA rely on the fact that all run in a thread using the thread local and JDBC is a blocking IO api..... in few word use mysql postgress and so on is possible but not efficient and in some case dangerous.

The good news is that exist some framework that fill this gap many of those are experimental but it is possible R2DBC is a case.

It is very beatifull framework.

It is a sample taken from a my repo on github it is built on spring boot 2.1 and kotlin but in java the syntax is very similar:

**web layer**

```
@Configuration
class ReservationRoutesConfig {

    @Bean
    fun reservationRoutes(@Value("\${baseServer:http://localhost:8080}") baseServer: String,
                          reservationRepository: ReservationRepository) =
            router {
                POST("/reservation") {
                    it.bodyToMono(ReservationRepresentation::class.java)
                            .flatMap { Mono.just(ReservationRepresentation.toDomain(reservationRepresentation = it)) }
                            .flatMap { reservationRepository.save(it).toMono() }
                            .flatMap { ServerResponse.created(URI("$baseServer/reservation/${it.reservationId}")).build() }

                }

                GET("/reservation/{reservationId}") {
                    reservationRepository.findOne(it.pathVariable("reservationId")).toMono()
                            .flatMap { Mono.just(ReservationRepresentation.toRepresentation(it)) }
                            .flatMap { ok().body(BodyInserters.fromObject(it)) }
                }

                DELETE("/reservation/{reservationId}") {
                    reservationRepository.delete(it.pathVariable("reservationId")).toMono()
                            .then(noContent().build())
                }
            }
}
```

**repository layer:**

```
class ReactiveReservationRepository(private val databaseClient: TransactionalDatabaseClient,
                                    private val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) : ReservationRepository {

    override fun findOne(reservationId: String): Publisher<Reservation> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.find(reservationId).toMono()
                        .flatMap { customer ->
                            it.execute().sql("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE reservation_id=$1")
                                    .bind("$1", reservationId)
                                    .exchange()
                                    .flatMap { sqlRowMap ->
                                        sqlRowMap.extract { t, u ->
                                            Reservation(t.get("reservation_id", String::class.java)!!,
                                                    t.get("restaurant_name", String::class.java)!!,
                                                    customer, t.get("date", LocalDateTime::class.java)!!)
                                        }.one()
                                    }
                        }
            }

    override fun save(reservation: Reservation): Publisher<Reservation> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.save(reservation.reservationId, reservation.customer).toMono()
                        .then(it.execute().sql("INSERT INTO reservation (reservation_id, restaurant_name, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
                                .bind("$1", reservation.reservationId)
                                .bind("$2", reservation.restaurantName)
                                .bind("$3", reservation.date)
                                .fetch().rowsUpdated())
            }.then(Mono.just(reservation))


    override fun delete(reservationId: String): Publisher<Void> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.delete(reservationId).toMono()
                        .then(it.execute().sql("DELETE FROM reservation WHERE reservation_id = $1")
                                .bind("$1", reservationId)
                                .fetch().rowsUpdated())
            }.then(Mono.empty())

}
```

I hope that can help you